# HP Proliant MicroServer locked up?

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, password, password-reset

This is my first time on Serverfault, so be gentle :)

My boss bought a Second-hand MicroServer, loaded with Windows Server 2003 R2, from a business that went bust very recently. Now, he wants to add this Server to his existing Server-Cabinet for RAID Controlling and Data Flow. The problem is that the Server is locked up tight, very tight, and I just can't seem to figure out a way to get into this MicroServer.

The Servers default credentials are set to the Administrator Account, but what makes matters worse is that this Server was locked on the previous company's domain prior to us purchasing it. We have tried contacting the previous owner, but he himself is clueless as what the password could be. Is there any tool out there that can unlock this MicroServer?

Here is a list of the things I have tried:

1. I tried using a Linux Distro, Kali Linux, to see where the OS is stored and change the admin password, but there was nothing to be found.
2. I have used Trinity Rescue Kit to try and salvage the Server, but TRK cannot pinpoint exactly where the local machine OS is stored (i.e /sda1/ or /sda2/), so that went pear-shaped very quickly.
3. I then tried Offline NT Password Recovery and Registry Editor, it crashed on boot, stating that Linux cannot be booted due to unknown reasons, and then reboots to the default Windows Server OS

Is there anything else that I can try to open this MicroServer up?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just reinstall Windows. Or, even better, install a newer Windows that is still supported.

Comment: It had crossed my mind, but I do not have access to an install disc.

Comment: Then get one. You have no idea what is installed on it. It could be loaded with malware. Reinstalling is the only prudent way to handle this.

Comment: That is true. I will speak to my boss ASAP about this. I really do appreciate the advice